# Django-Channels: Schedule jobs

Tags: python, websocket, redis, django-channels

I am working on an application similar to a quiz model. My requirement is,

1. The web socket server should be able to send time updates - say each question has 30 sec time, i need a scheduled job which will send 30,29,28.....0 to the web socket client.
2. Once the time is up, i need one more functionality to send the next question to the web socket client(i.e., it should be 30 sec interval job).

Note: I am usign AsyncWebSocketConsumer as my base consumer.

Can anyone help me with good design on how i can implement this functionality and some code snippets/tutorials in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I think the count should be done on the quizz page, and one finished the answer is sent to the server.

On the server you can also control that the question has been answer in 30s.

Comment: In my requirement, it is required to maintain all the timers and logics on server side instead of client. Can we have any design for that please?

Comment: Well in that case then you can use Celery, RabbitMQ or even CRON  to schedule jobs. But even a python script that send a number then wait then send another number etc

Comment: But not a good architecture IMO

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).